# ASP ListBox returns -1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a an ASP listBox. Whenever I select a new item in the list, the following function gets called:

```
 protected void prevSubList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox index
        int index = prevSubList.SelectedIndex;
        if (index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        //get the nominee for that index
        Nominees currNominee = nominees[index];
        populateFields(currNominee);
    }


<td ID="previousSubmissions" align="left">
    <asp:ListBox ID="prevSubList" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="263px" 
     Rows="1" onselectedindexchanged="prevSubList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="True">
     </asp:ListBox>
</td>
```

The problem is `int index = prevSubList.SelectedIndex;` always evaluates to -1. There are three items in my list, say I select the second one, I would expect the value to be 1, but it is -1. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it possible you reset the value or clear the list on every postback?

Comment: @Kobi well what do you know, that fixed it. Thanks. Sorry, I am new to all of this.

Comment: Are you populating drop down values in the `populateFields()` method? It could be that you'are using smething like Items.Clear() which reset index

Answer (score 2):

You are probably binding the data on Page_Load and you are not checking whether IsPostBack is true.

Example:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
      Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       data.Add("i" + i, "i" + i);    

       prevSubList.DataSource = data;
       prevSubList.DataBind();
}
```